# How can I rotate a conic gradient

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to make the bar on the conic gradient rotate infinitely in a circle? [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcPPx.png) is how the gradient looks, I just want it to rotate around the center but everything I have tried hasn't worked.

Comment: `everything I have tried` like what? you've shown nothing you've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want, just make sure you have (at least) 3 colours, and the final colour is the same as the first

P.S. I added rotation because wasn't sure what you meant by infinite rotation

```css
div {
position:relative;
height:200px;
overflow:hidden;
aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
border: solid black 1px;
clip-path: border-box;
}
div::before {
z-index:-1;
content:'';
position:absolute;
inset: -25%;
background-image: conic-gradient(
    hsl(297.3, 84.6%, 20.4%),
    hsl(192.6, 51.4%, 58.0%),
    hsl(297.3, 84.6%, 20.4%)
);
animation: 3s linear infinite rot;
}
@keyframes rot {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Hello World</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the start angle, as well as move the center of your conical gradient with `from <angle> <centerX> <center Y>`.

```
background-image: conic-gradient(
    from -90deg,
    hsl(297.3, 84.6%, 20.4%),
    hsl(192.6, 51.4%, 58.0%),
    hsl(297.3, 84.6%, 20.4%)
);
```